# Wordpress: Unpacking the package… Could not create directory

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, plugins, wordpress

On my website i am using apache: 2.2.22 and wordpress: 4.2.10,

Since i enabled my website to have ftp access, every plugin update or installation gives me the error:

```
Unpacking the package…  
Could not create directory
```

My vhost configs:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName www.website.com
        ServerAlias website.com

        DocumentRoot /home/website.com/htdocs
        <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
                AssignUserId ftp-user ftp-user
        </IfModule>

        <Directory /home/website.com/htdocs>
                php_admin_value open_basedir /home/website.com/htdocs:/tmp
               php_admin_value safe_mode On
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>



........
</VirtualHost>
```

I am making setfacl for the apache "www-data" user as rwx permission all over the "/home/website.com/htdocs" recursively,

```
-rwxrwxr-x+  1 ftp-user ftp-group    32  mywot23b6b47ec20c5b6cd50d.html
-rwxrwxr-x+  1 ftp-user ftp-group  7361  readme.html
drwxrwxr-x+  2 ftp-user ftp-group  4096  tracking
-rw-rwxr--+  1 ftp-user ftp-group  2085  unsubscribezoho.php
-rwxrwxr-x+  1 ftp-user ftp-group  4951  wp-activate.php
drwxrwxr-x+ 11 ftp-user ftp-group  4096  wp-admin
-rwxrwxr-x+  1 ftp-user ftp-group   271  wp-blog-header.php
-rwxrwxr-x+  1 ftp-user ftp-group  5007  wp-comments-post.php
-rwxrwxr-x+  1 ftp-user ftp-group  3687  wp-config.php
-rwxrwxr-x+  1 ftp-user ftp-group  2727  wp-config-sample.php
drwxrwxr-x+  8 ftp-user ftp-group  4096  wp-content
-rwxrwxr-x+  1 ftp-user ftp-group  3115  wp-cron.php
drwxrwxr-x+ 13 ftp-user ftp-group  4096  wp-includes
-rwxrwxr-x+  1 ftp-user ftp-group  2380  wp-links-opml.php
-rwxrwxr-x+  1 ftp-user ftp-group  3123  wp-load.php
-rwxrwxr-x+  1 ftp-user ftp-group 34241  wp-login.php
-rwxrwxr-x+  1 ftp-user ftp-group  8252  wp-mail.php
-rwxrwxr-x+  1 ftp-user ftp-group 11048  wp-settings.php
```

I tried to grant "777" to wp-content recursively (plugins, upgrades folders) didn't work, and tried to change the ownership to apache user "www-data", but the plugins are gone in the admin page!

Please Help!

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue just recently and found a fix.

You need to change permissions on the folders inside wp-content folder:

```
    sudo find /var/www/wordpress/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
    sudo find /var/www/wordpress/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

After you've done that, add the following to your wp-config.php file and it should work just fine.

```
    define('FS_METHOD','direct');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just had this issue, took me a whole day to figure that out.

Check that `user` and `group` in /etc/php/php-fpm.d/www.conf are set to `www-data`. By default it's `http`.